# php data testing

Tags: php

I have the following test on some data:

```
if(isset($option_type)
    && ($option_type == 3 || $option_type == 4
                && (isset($ext_data) && $ext_data != "")
                )
  ){}
```

What it should do, is if $option type is NOT 3 or 4, the test should return true. If $option type is 3 or 4 AND $ext_data does not exist or equals "", then the test should return false.

However, no matter what $option_type is, it returns false.

How can I format this test so when the $option_type is 3 or 4 and $ext_data exists and is not "", the result is true?

lee

Comment: a quick suggestion here, separate them out and return them, see what they return (true or false), then organize the order from there

Comment: Two words: [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). It might not immediately fix your test, but the current code is most likely not what you want.

Comment: I know a little about operator precedence. However, I'm not sure that applies here since all the outer testing uses && and the inner testing is parenthesized. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The `&&` on your third line only applies if `$option_type == 4`. Due to lazy logic, if `$option_type == 3` the code won't even bother computing the third line.

Comment: Thanks Palladium. I just did a bunch of reading and understand a little more. I still am not clear exactly why my test is not working, but I got some new knowledge for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the tests into two to make it clearer:

```
if (!isset($ext_data) || $ext_data == "") return false;
return $option_type != 3 && $option_type != 4;
```

Comment: Hello, I can do this, no problem. But I am curious to know why the test as it is does not work or what is not clear about it. I've used similar testing in ActionScript and C# with no problem. Is it a PHP thing? Is it just incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

//try this

```
if(isset($option_type)&& ($option_type == 3 || $option_type == 4)){
    if (isset($ext_data) && $ext_data == ""){
            return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

  }
```